# Unfoldable instance for the cofree comonad

Tags: haskell, comonad, unfold

I'm trying to figure out the difference between `unfold/coiter` from `Control.Comonad.Cofree` and `unfold/ana` from `Data.Control.Fixedpoint`. Hackage libraries are resp. `free` and `recursion-schemes`.

`Cofree` and `Fix` seem to be cousins, and I'm trying to figure out what is possible with both and what is possible with only one of them.

I could write an instance of `Foldable` for `Cofree` so I can apply `cata` to a free monad obtained from `unfold/coiter`:

```
type instance Base (Cofree f a) = f

instance Functor f => Foldable (Cofree f a) where
    project = unwrap
```

But I couldn't construct an `Unfoldable` instance:

```
instance Functor f => Unfoldable (Cofree f a) where
    embed = xembed

xembed :: Functor f => f (Cofree f a) -> Cofree f a 
xembed = undefined
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't write this function for `Cofree` in general. Consider `f ~ Proxy` (where `data Proxy a = Proxy`):

```
xembed :: Proxy (Cofree Proxy a) -> Cofree Proxy a
-- i.e.
xembed :: () -> a
```

Has to get an `a` out of nowhere.

However, you can write `xembed` for `Free`: `wrap :: f (Free f a) -> Free f a`. And similarly you can't write `xproject :: Free f a -> f (Free f a)` in general.

Comment: Do you mean I can't write `project` for free monads, and `embed` for free comonads?

Comment: Yes, I fixed that (it's a cofree comonad, not a free comonad! :-) ). However, now that I looked at what these classes actually are, maybe your `Base` type is just not what you want (I'm not quite sure what you're after there). `Cofree f a` is the fixed point of `\self -> (a,f self)` and `Free f a` is the fixed point of `\self -> Either a (f self)`, not just of `f`.